# MongoDB : "unexpected token" error when trying to Update document field that is an array

Tags: arrays, mongodb

I have a collection called Names with a document that looks like this:

```
{
   "_id":33,
   "listOfNames" : ["John", "Fred", "Andy"]
}
```

I am trying to do an update command that looks like the following:

```
db.Names.update{{}, {$set: {"listOfNames" : ["John", "Mary"]}, {multi:true})}
```

This fails with "unexpected token". What is the correct syntax to use when updating a field in a series of documents when the field is an array?

Answer (score 3):

use this query

```
db.Names.update({}, 
{
    $set: {"listOfNames":["John", "Mary"]},     
}, { multi : true })
```

- Anyway you put redundant `{` after update function, You should use `(`
- And you put `)` in wrong place